# How can I generate a downloadable video with a custom watermark in browser?

Tags: video

I have a video file that I want users to be able to download from my website, but an important part of that is the video needs to contain their brand logo as an irremovable watermark.  Is there any way to add the watermark automatically using JavaScript, jQuery, PHP or something else?

EDIT:  It is a Wordpress site with shared hosting if that makes a difference.

Comment: To clarify, you want to serve the video to the public WITHOUT adding the watermark to the original video itself, but at the same time enforce a restriction where users downloading the video end up with a watermarked video file, correct?

Comment: easiest will be to use something like ffmpeg to add the bug to the video before you upload it. if the video can be played then (unless you want to use a DRM service) people will be able to download it if they want to. Plyr.io does support a different 'download' url to the played file which might be good enough for what you want

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes because the watermark will be provided by the user, and I want the watermarked video to be generated automatically and be available for download once it is ready.